# How to define my own helm template functions

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm

I need to provide a string in a helm template that is then sha256 encrypted and dumped out as a hexdigest, then pushed into a json structure.

Currently I have a values file like

Users:
   - userid: Santa
     passwd: Claus

and I'm defining a secret like

users.json: {{ .Values.Users | toJson | b64enc }}

but I want the passwd field encrypted as expected by the application. I'm not aware of any helper in helm that provides sha256 encryption so I'm wondering if I can supply my own, and then what the syntax would look like.

Help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Helm exposes in it's templates most of the functions implemented in [Sprig](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig), which includes cryptographic functions as well - it includes [sha256](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/crypto.html#sha256sum) as well.

(As a side note, sha256 is not an encryption algorithm, it's a hash function)